# Basics on using custom Beamer usage

Tags: beamer, customize

I have been using LaTex only for documents and my knowledge about customizing is REALLY basic. However I would like to create my own beamer style and I found the info I think I need in [here in StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch?answertab=votes#tab-top) and in [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/12/07/how-to-make-a-presentation-in-latex/) . They both said to store all the files created for the format in one directory. However, where do I need to store the directory so that my TexStudio finds it? I am using a Linux Mint and I have tried some of the hints in this [question from StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202312/problems-installing-custom-beamer-style-on-mac) although it was asked for macOS. No luck with that one either. Any help will be greatly appreciated ;-)

Comment: The easiest way is to place your custom .sty files in the same folder as your .tex file. If you want to reuse your theme in many presentations, you could place the folder in your textmf folder, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138/36296 (to get started and while you design your custom theme, I would leave them in the same folder as your presentation, this makes going back and forth between the files easier)

Comment: (to get started and while you design your custom theme, I would leave them in the same folder as your presentation, this makes going back and forth between the files easier)

Comment: Thanks! For some reason the textmf is not in my linux (or I cannot find it). What I understood from your answer:  I store all the 4 (beamerinnerthemestyle.sty, beamerouterthemestyle.sty, beamercolorthemestyle.sty, beamerthemestyle.sty) files directly in the same directory of my tex file, same level. Did I get it right?

Comment: The folder does not exist by default, but you can make it. Yes, all the .sty files go in the same folder at the same level as your .tex file and then latex will find them automatically. That's the easiest way to start.

Comment: Depending on how complicate your theme is going to be, you could also put all the code into the `beamerthemestyle.sty` file and avoid all the files `beamercolorthemestyle.sty` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will play around with it!